# get memory from ps and compare via bash with my limit

Tags: bash, awk, ps

I have code that I use in openwrt. I need to check memory which use application

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(ps | grep sca | grep start | awk '{print $3}')
VAG=$(cat /proc/pid/status | grep -e ^VmSize | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $VAG>28000 ]
then
echo test
fi
```

No matter if I use VAR or VEG(for example VAR/VAG equal 15000), I can get work this code. I always get "test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. The `test` command (aka `[`) must receive separate arguments for the operands and the operator. Also, `>` is for string comparisons; you need to use `-gt` instead.

```
if [ "$VAG" -gt 28000 ]
```

Since you are using `bash`, you can use the more readable arithmetic command instead of `[`:

```
if (( VAG > 28000 ))
```